# Querying with nHibernate where todays date is between publishDate and Expiry date

Tags: nhibernate, date, date-range, nhibernate-criteria

I am trying to figure out how to best query in NHibernate so that the returned results are between for entries where todays time is >= PublishDateTime and <=ExpiryDateTime

The expiry date can be null so I need to allow for that. I found a couple of examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/DateTimeRange.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139846/nhibernate-criteria-query-help) but they seem to work in a different way and accept 2 values and compare to one DB field. I want the other way wrong really.

Query so far:

```
var query = _session.CreateCriteria<Message>()
                .AddOrder(Order.Desc("PublishedDateTime"))
                .List<Message>();
                return query;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly received!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easiest Linq query:

```
return _session.Query<Message>()
               .Where(m => DateTime.Today >= m.PublishDateTime &&
                          (m.ExpiryDateTime == null ||
                           DateTime.Now <= m.ExpiryDateTime)
               .OrderByDescending(m => m.PublishDateTime)
               .ToList();
```

Criteria:

```
return _session.CreateCriteria<Message>()
               .Add(Restrictions.Le("PublishedDateTime", DateTime.Today) & 
                                    (Restrictions.IsNull("ExpiryDateTime") |
                                     Restrictions.Ge("ExpiryDateTime",
                                                     DateTime.Now)))
               .AddOrder(Order.Desc("PublishedDateTime"))
               .List<Message>();
```

Comment: +1 thanks for giving both examples. Linq I new but was interested in the Criteria method so thank you

Comment: Do me a favour just change .Today to .Now and I'll mark you as the answer. Thanks again for your input :)

Comment: I thought you wanted "today's date", not "current time" (that's what the question says)

Comment: sorry meant date time - I've mislead with worded but worded correctly on the fields - will update now - thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

In c# :

```
          var formato = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss";
            var sDesde = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " 0:00:00";
            var sHasta = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss");

            Viaje vDesde = new Viaje { Viajefecha = DateTime.ParseExact(sDesde, formato , null) };
            Viaje vHasta = new Viaje { Viajefecha = DateTime.ParseExact(sHasta, formato, null) };

            StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
            var resultado = cp.sesion.CreateCriteria<Viaje>().Add(Expression.Between("Viajefecha", vDesde.Viajefecha, vHasta.Viajefecha)).AddOrder(Order.Asc("Viajefecha")).List<Viaje>();
```