# I have Two Dates 'Begin Date' and ' End Date' in asp.net MVC, I want to run a loop start from 'Begin Date' to 'End Date'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to run a loop in Asp.net MVC using two dates and want to fetch all data from database that exist between these two dates, Please help me.

Comment: Why you can't fetch them in SQL query to your database with use of BETWEEN keyword?

Comment: I am using Razor coding inside view in MVC, so that i am not using between keyword.

Comment: Sergey Litvinov is right , try to use sql query to fetch values from database. created a sample sqlfiddle here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e887/6/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make it via Razor, then you can use such code:

```
@for (DateTime item = model.BeginDate; item <= model.EndDate; item = item.AddDays(1))
{
    <div>Date is @item</div>
}
```

But if you need to fetch data from DB, it will be better to include it in the SQL query that fetch this data with [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) keyword. Here is a sample:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeSource WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @endDate
```

**UPDATE1**
I didn't use nHibernate before, but seems there is an answer on SO about it - [Querying with nHibernate where todays date is between publishDate and Expiry date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368623/querying-with-nhibernate-where-todays-date-is-between-publishdate-and-expiry-dat)

Basically you can write such code:

```
DateTime beginDate, endDate;
// init datetime values
return _session.CreateCriteria<Message>()
           .Add(
                  Restrictions.Le("BeginDate", beginDate) 
                  & Restrictions.Ge("EndDate", endDate))
           .List<SomeResultType>();
```

Comment: Can you please help me in writing sql code inside view, i am using nhibernate , between clause is not working

Comment: I didn't use nHibernate, but i found a sample on SO and updated answer